# Issue while migrating from webpack 1.x to webpack 2.x. No ESLint configuration found

Tags: javascript, configuration, webpack, webpack-2

I am migrating a project from Webpack 1 to Webpack 2. I am having problems integrating eslint. In my Webpack 1 config, I have eslint configured as such:

`eslint: {
    configFile: path.join(__dirname, "eslint.core.js"),
    useEslintrc: false
}`

The config above works fine. In Webpack 2, I have it under the plugins property

`plugins: [ 
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({ 
        options: { 
            eslint: { 
                configFile: path.join(__dirname, "eslint.core.js"), 
                useEslintrc: false 
            } 
        } 
    }
) ]`

In the terminal, I am receiving the error `Module build failed: Error: No ESLint configuration found`. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

I am using: 

`"webpack": "2.2.0-rc.3"
"eslint": "3.5.0"
"eslint-loader": "1.5.0"
"eslint-plugin-mocha": "4.5.1"
"eslint-plugin-react": "6.2.2"`

Answer (score 2):

I've had `Module build failed: Error: No ESLint configuration found` too.
For me the solution was moving all the eslint-loader options from LoaderOptionsPlugin right to rules. See my webpack.config.js below.
My eslint configuration file eslint_conf.js is exact copy of usual .eslintrc.js placed in project's root catalog.

```js
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/src",
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    emitWarning: true,
                    emitError: true,
                    //failOnWarning: false,
                    //failOnError: true,
                    useEslintrc: false,
                    // configFile: path.join(__dirname, "eslint_conf.js")
                    configFile: "eslint_conf.js"
                }
            },
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]&outputPath=../dist/' },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [{
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: {
                                autoprefixer: true,
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoaders: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "fast-sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                // sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery'
        })

    ]
};
```

To run eslint by `npm run lintjs` I have scripts in package.json like this:

```
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --watch webpack.config.js --exec \"webpack-dev-server --env development\"",
    "lintjs": "eslint src --cache --no-eslintrc -c eslint_conf.js",
    "build": "webpack --env production"
  }
```

I use:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.2",
    "eslint": "^3.17.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "fast-sass-loader": "^1.0.7",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "inuitcss": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^2.9.0",
    "postcss-import": "^9.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

run `eslint --init` in the root
This will generate a config file for you
just use the following in the webpack conf

```
{
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: eslint-loader
       }
     ]
}
```